# How to prove Variance of response residuals of Poisson distribution changes with mean

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals, poisson-regression

It is intuitive that spread of the response residuals changes with mean.

But, I am not sure how can I prove this mathematically.

If $y_{i} \sim Po(\lambda_{i})$, what is Var$(y_{i} - \hat{y}_{i})$?

Comment: When $y_i$ follows a Poisson distribution with $\lambda_i$, then the mean *and* variance of $y_i$ are equal to $\lambda_i$. If $\hat{y_i}$ denotes the conditional expectation of $y_i$, then the residuals $y_i - \hat{y_i}$ should have the same variance as $y_i$, namely $\lambda_i$

Comment: Write down the density function of the Poisson distribution, and then calculate $Var(Y) = E((Y-\lambda)^2)$ through the definition of an expectation. This should give you $Var(Y) = E(Y) =  \lambda$ again

Comment: In here $\hat{y}_{i}$'s are model fitted values. Like in linear regression $Var(y - \hat{y}) = Var(y - Hy) = (I - H) \sigma^2$, where $H$ is the hat matrix. What I have defined above is not $Var(y - E(y|x))$.

Comment: I see. Residuals based approaches are really rare for Poisson regression models, because their is no location shift as with linear regression. Hence not much sensible can be said about raw residuals